# gammu-smsd daemon not sending SMS messages

Tags: sms-gateway

I noticed that my gammu-smsd daemon running on Ubuntu is suddenly not sending messages (the sentitems table of my postgresql database is not being updated). First, I noticed that the damemon was not running so I restarted it:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/gammu-smsd start
 * Starting Gammu SMS Daemon gammu-smsd    [ OK ]
```

Then I checked the syslog (which is the log I configured gammu-smsd to report to):

```
Jun 27 15:33:04 porkypig gammu-smsd[19267]: Configuring Gammu SMSD...
Jun 27 15:33:04 porkypig gammu-smsd[19267]: SHM token: 0xffffffffce020154 (-838729388)
Jun 27 15:33:04 porkypig gammu-smsd[19267]: Warning: No PIN code in /etc/gammu-smsdrc file
Jun 27 15:33:04 porkypig gammu-smsd[19267]: commtimeout=30, sendtimeout=30, receivefrequency=0, resetfrequency=0
Jun 27 15:33:04 porkypig gammu-smsd[19267]: checks: security=1, battery=0, signal=1
Jun 27 15:33:04 porkypig gammu-smsd[19267]: deliveryreport = no
Jun 27 15:33:04 porkypig gammu-smsd[19267]: phoneid =
Jun 27 15:33:04 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Using PGSQL service
Jun 27 15:33:04 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Connected to database: smsd on localhost. Server version: 80414 Protocol: 3
Jun 27 15:33:05 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Database structures version: 11, SMSD current version: 11
Jun 27 15:33:05 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Table check succeeded
Jun 27 15:33:05 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Starting phone communication...
Jun 27 15:33:22 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Error at init connection No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected. (14)
Jun 27 15:33:22 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Terminating communication No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected., (14, 250 times)
Jun 27 15:33:22 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Starting phone communication...
Jun 27 15:33:32 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Error at init connection No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected. (14)
Jun 27 15:33:32 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Terminating communication No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected., (14, 250 times)
Jun 27 15:33:32 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Starting phone communication...
Jun 27 15:33:42 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Error at init connection No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected. (14)
Jun 27 15:33:42 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Terminating communication No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected., (14, 250 times)
Jun 27 15:33:42 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Starting phone communication...
Jun 27 15:33:52 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Error at init connection No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected. (14)
Jun 27 15:33:52 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Terminating communication No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected., (14, 250 times)
Jun 27 15:33:52 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Going to 30 seconds sleep because of too much connection errors
Jun 27 15:34:22 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Starting phone communication...
Jun 27 15:34:32 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Error at init connection No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected. (14)
Jun 27 15:34:32 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Terminating communication No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected., (14, 250 times)
Jun 27 15:34:32 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Going to 30 seconds sleep because of too much connection errors
Jun 27 15:35:02 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Starting phone communication...
Jun 27 15:35:12 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Error at init connection No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected. (14)
Jun 27 15:35:12 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Terminating communication No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected., (14, 250 times)
Jun 27 15:35:12 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Going to 30 seconds sleep because of too much connection errors
Jun 27 15:35:42 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Starting phone communication...
Jun 27 15:35:52 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Error at init connection No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected. (14)
Jun 27 15:35:52 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Terminating communication No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected., (14, 250 times)
Jun 27 15:35:52 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Going to 30 seconds sleep because of too much connection errors
Jun 27 15:36:22 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Starting phone communication...
Jun 27 15:36:32 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Error at init connection No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected. (14)
Jun 27 15:36:32 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Terminating communication No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected., (14, 250 times)
Jun 27 15:36:32 porkypig gammu-smsd[19268]: Going to 30 seconds sleep because of too much connection errors
```

Does this mean that the modem plugged into the serial port of the computer is not responding? (I access the machine via ssh and I don't want to have to physically go to computer if not required.)

Note though that I can run `sudo minicom` and get the following:

```
Welcome to minicom 2.4

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Jan 25 2010, 07:02:36.
Port /dev/ttyS0

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys
```

However, minicom does not let me type any at commands in the window. It just shows a blinking cursor. While I am able to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> and other <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> shortcuts to access menus, I am unable to type any at commands in the window.

The minicom log looks like this:

```
$ cat minicom.log
20130610 17:57:50 Hangup (0:10:29)
20130611 10:47:56 Gone offline (0:00:02)
20130611 10:53:59 Hangup (0:00:00)
20130611 12:51:50 Hangup (0:00:00)
20130612 00:43:39 Hangup (0:00:00)
20130616 21:45:54 Hangup (0:00:07)
20130624 14:22:48 Hangup (0:01:43)
20130624 14:26:02 Hangup (0:02:58)
20130624 16:58:52 Hangup (2:19:25)
20130625 15:04:39 Hangup (0:03:54)
20130626 10:43:19 Hangup (0:08:13)
20130627 15:46:02 Hangup (0:00:35)
```

Any idea why the SMS messages are not being sent?

Comment: hah, same happened to my ZTE USB modem this week, unplug/plug didn't help.

Comment: unplug/plug actually did work for me

Comment: Minicom "not letting you type any AT commands" means the modem is not echoing back anything you type. It might mean the modem has command echo disabled (`ATE0`): in that case if you type blindly `at` or `AT` and press Enter, you should still get back an `OK` response. Or if you get no response at all, it could mean that the modem's internal firmware is hung. If unplug/plug worked for you, the latter seems a possible explanation.

Answer (score 1):

please run gammu-config using current user and..

edit `/etc/init.d/gammu-smsd`

```
# user which will run this daemon
USER=USERNAME
```

eg

```
USER=apis17
```

default user is gammu and it has no `.gammurc` file on `/home/gammu` folder